# An example when List<?> is not the same as List<Object>

Tags: java, generics, type-conversion

It is made in java, that generics are not automatically converted from `Generic<A>` to `Generic<SupeclassOfA>`.

For example, if write a method

```
public static void printList(List<Object> list) {
    for (Object elem : list)
        System.out.println(elem + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

it will not accept `List<Integer>`. I need to rewrite header for `List<?>` and it will start work although the code will be the same.

So, why is it done?

Suppose I redesign `Java` so that `List<?>` always mean the same as `List<Object>`. What problems will I face?

Comment: Try to add something into the List(s).

Comment: This question has, in many guises, been asked tens of times on SO. Please search through existing questions first.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a method taking a `List<Object>` accepted a `List<Integer>`. That would mean `List<Integer>` was a subtype of `List<Object>`. If that were true you could do this:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Object> objList = (List<Object>) intList;
objList.add("foo");
int a = intList.get(0);  // This would fail at runtime because intList.get(0) is a String.
```

So if you could cast a `List<Integer>` to a `List<Object>` you would lose the compile-time type safe safety that generics provide.

`List<?>` is not the same as `List<Object>`. `List<?>` is a `List` of some unknown type `T`. Since `T` is unknown it is not possible to add anything to a `List<?>` (except `null`). This is in complete contrast to a `List<Object>` where you can add anything.

As a general rule, `List<Object>` is very rarely what you need. Most of the time you want a `List` where all the items have the same type, like a `List<Integer>` or a `List<String>`. If you are writing a method where the type is not important, such as your example that just prints the items, the argument should have type `List<?>`.

Answer (score 0):

You also are able to declare a upper bound. So you say :

```
List<? extends Foo> list
```

this will cause that you only are able to to things in the list which are subclasses of foo. 
in you case write extends Object. So Integer is a subclass an can be inserted.